# Grow grouped pandas data frame by iteratively comparing the previous element of another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

My question relates to another question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60159211/grow-pandas-dataframe-group-by-group) but is different since two columns are concerned.

I have a pandas data frame with for multiple groups (vehicles) the departure and arrival time on a specific day. These times are stored as strings, such that e.g. '2330' corresponds to 11.30pm and '30' to 0.30am. These moments in time are ordered chronologically but may sometimes cross the midnight line. I want to indicate these moments by a 1 in a new column. More specifically, I think I need to check (1) for each departure time whether it is 'earlier' than the arrival time of the previous record (this implies the departure must be on a new day) and (2) for each arrival time whether it is earlier than the departure time of the current record (this implies the arrival must be on a new day).

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.{'group' : ["A","A","A","B","B","B"],
                   'departure' : [2030, 2300, 200, 1930, 200, 300],
                   'arrival' : [2130, 30, 230, 100, 230, 400]})
```

Yields

```
  group  departure  arrival
0     A       2030     2130
1     A       2300       30
2     A        200      230
3     B       1930      100
4     B        200      230
5     B        300      400
```

Desired output:

```
  group  departure  arrival  dep_new  arr_new
0     A       2030     2130  0        0
1     A       2300       30  0        1
2     A        200      230  1        1
3     B       1930      100  0        1
4     B        200      230  1        1
5     B        300      400  1        1
```

Application of the answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60159211/grow-pandas-dataframe-group-by-group), by comparing the current arrival to the previous arrival and the current departure to the previous departure, would probably not work because there are some corner cases that would not be handled correctly using this approach.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : ["A","A","A","B","B","B"],
                   'departure' : [2030, 2300, 200, 1930, 200, 300],
                   'arrival' : [2130, 30, 230, 100, 230, 400]})
dep_new = list()
arr_new = list()

for grp in df.groupby('group'):
    dep_new.append((grp[1].arrival < grp[1].departure).astype(int))
    arr_new.append((grp[1].departure > grp[1].arrival.shift(1)).astype(int))

arr_new_flat = list()
for sublist in arr_new:
    for item in sublist:
        arr_new_flat.append(item)

dep_new_flat = list()
for sublist in dep_new:
    for item in sublist:
        dep_new_flat.append(item)

df['dep_new'] = dep_new_flat
df['arr_new'] = arr_new_flat

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  group  departure  arrival  dep_new  arr_new
0     A       2030     2130        0        0
1     A       2300       30        1        1
2     A        200      230        0        1
3     B       1930      100        1        0
4     B        200      230        0        1
5     B        300      400        0        1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, since it may happen (and in fact often does) that there is in a group also an earlier record, at the beginning of the day, between, say, 900 (9am) and 1000 (10am). These records are NOT to be registered as a new day. Sorry, my small sample example does not cover this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and effort! This is almost what I need; however not entirely. If I understand correctly, your solution does not consider each group individually. As a result, in your solution, I believe the first record for each group is not (always) computed correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer, but concerning groups gives a slightly different result compared to your (original) question.

Comment: I think there should be a mistake in this line: arr_new.append((grp[1].departure > grp[1].arrival.shift(1)).astype(int)) . This says that if the departure time is LARGER than the previous arrival time, then this means that it is a new day (if I am correct). This is however not what we need. I am not sure why it yields the correct output here. 

However with the inspiration of your answer (especially the shift() operator) I think I managed to find an answer that I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Rene, I think I managed to find a solution.

```
def _activity_nextday(df):
    deppivot = (df.departure < df.arrival.shift(1)).astype(int) # if departure is "before" arrival on previous day, then this means that departure is on new day
    arrpivot = (df.arrival < df.departure).astype(int)  # if arrival is "before" departure, then this means that arrival is on new day

    agglist = [None] * (len(arrpivot) + len(deppivot))
    agglist[::2] = deppivot
    agglist[1::2] = arrpivot
    cumlist = list(np.array(agglist).cumsum())
    d_cum = cumlist[::2]
    a_cum = cumlist[1::2]

    return pd.DataFrame({"dep_new" : d_cum, "arr_new": a_cum})

df[["dep_new", "arr_new"]] = df.groupby("group").apply(lambda x: _activity_nextday(x)).reset_index(level="group").reset_index(drop=False)[["dep_new", "arr_new"]]
```

Result:

```
  group  departure  arrival  dep_new  arr_new
0     A       2030     2130        0        0
1     A       2300     2330        0        0
2     A        200      230        1        1
3     B       1930      100        0        1
4     B        200      230        1        1
5     B        300      400        1        1
```